# How to listen to GET param in laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to listen to simple get param (test param) in laravel middleware.
here is my code

```
Route::middleware('api')->get('/betshistory', function (Request $request) {

return $request->user();
});
```

here is my url:
http://localhost:8080/api/betshistory?test=45

i tried doing this:

```
    print_r($request->parameter('test'));
print_r(Route::current()->parameter('test'));
print_r($request->route()->paremeters('test'));
```

but i cannot catch it.
what am i missing?
Thanks

Comment: have you looked what's actually inside your $request? With dd($request);

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input - `$request->input('name')`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this section of the documentation related to [retreiving input](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input).

From there you could do:

```
$test = $request->parameter('test');
```

Or, in case you want to limit the search to query parameters:

```
$test = $request->query('test');
```

Answer (score -1):

that was the answer

```
$request->input('name');
```

Thanks